# Gradle cant find support lib, Android

Tags: android, gradle

I have the build script from this project here:

https://github.com/melix/gr8confagenda/blob/master/gr8confagenda/build.gradle

But when I try to run the project, I get this error:

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':gr8confagenda'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':gr8confagenda:_debugCompile'.
   > Could not find com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0.
     Required by:
         gr8confagenda:gr8confagenda:unspecified
```

Where I'm making the mistake?

Comment: Right Click on Your Project. Goto Android-Tools -> Click on Add Support Library. As what i have understood is that it is requiring android.support.v4 library which is not added

Comment: I'm using intelli J. Where is Android-Tools?

Comment: http://www.in-nomine.org/2012/02/26/adding-android-support-v4-to-your-android-application-in-intellij-idea/